# TypeError: (intermediate value).parseFromString(...).replace is not a function

Tags: javascript, dom, typeerror

I want to display the parsedHtml into element. but before display it, I should change a bit html into parsedHtml. so I used replace for this like code. but it has `TypeError: (intermediate value).parseFromString(...).replace is not a function` issue. Could you help me to fix this issue? Thanks

```
const parsedHTML = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
const renderHtml = parsedHTML.replace('aria-expanded="false"', 'aria-expanded="true"');
console.log(renderHtml);
```

Comment: It seems the issue is because **.replace()** is a String function. The **parsedHTML** variable is not a string but rather a DOMParser object, so **.replace()** is not an available function. You will probably need to run the **.replace()** function on your variable called **html** *before* you pass it into the **parseFromString()** function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are treating a DOMParser object as a string. That will not work.

You need to do something like this since it is not recommended you change valid HTML before parsing it

```js
const html = `<html><div aria-expanded="false"></div></html>`
const parsedHTML = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
parsedHTML.querySelector("div").setAttribute("aria-expanded",true)
console.log(parsedHTML.querySelector("div"));
```